# websocket not working while adding fuction over join method

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to phoenix programming while I'm learning I'm following Stephen graders udemy course.

While creating a channel to create a comment section, it works finely on first code but when I made a function, the join method is not working properly.

```js
socket.connect();

let channel = socket.channel(`comments:1`, {});
channel
  .join()
  .receive('ok', resp => {
    console.log('Joined successfully', resp);
  })
  .receive('error', resp => {
    console.log('Unable to join', resp);
  });

export default socket;
```

it gives me a joined successfully response in my console.but when I make the function like this...

```js
socket.connect();
const createSocket = topicId => {
  let channel = socket.channel(`comments:%{topicId}`, {});
  channel
    .join()
    .receive('ok', resp => {
      console.log('Joined successfully', resp);
    })
    .receive('error', resp => {
      console.log('Unable to join', resp);
    });
};
window.createSocket = createSocket;
```

and I called in html file...

```html
<script>
  window.createSocket(<%= @topic.id %>)
</script>
```

while compiling I got an error that websocket disconnected while handshaking....

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use javascript string interpolation operator

```
`comments:${topicId}`
```

instead of

```
`comments:%{topicId}`
```

Note the `$` instead of `%`